# How to center a Imageview on the screen with a FrameLayout? (with java code)

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I need to center a imageview on the screen, but programatically, without using XML layouts.

I am actually using a FrameLayout, but i dont know how to center it on the FrameLayout.

This is the code i have until now:

```
        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    splash = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    splash.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
    splash.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    fl.addView(splash);
    fl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    setContentView(fl);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
fl.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: - center cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - gravity cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field

Answer (score 6):

I would think something like this would get it done for you:

```
    LayoutParams centerParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    centerParams.gravity =  Gravity.CENTER;
    fl.setLayoutParams(centerParams);
```

[check out this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams.html) for more info

Comment: i got error on the line "centerParams.gravity"    ---> gravity cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Which LayoutParams class did you import?

Answer (score 2):

Imageview has no gravity. It has layout_gravity.